# How to get object attribute using ctypes?

Tags: python, wrapper, ctypes

I'm newbie in Python and ctypes. I'm using [`pynfc`](https://github.com/ikelos/pynfc). This is a [`libnfc`](http://www.libnfc.org/api/index.html) wrap and I can't get attributes over a [`nfc_device`](http://www.libnfc.org/api/structnfc__device.html) struct.

I'm trying to get the device name as follows:

```
self.__device = nfc.nfc_open(self.__context, conn_strings[0])
print self.__device.name
```

but I get:

```
AttributeError: 'LP_struct_nfc_device' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: `print self.__device.value.name` perhaps?

Comment: Hi. Nop. Same error but with 'value' instead of 'name'